# How to add a .crt certificate to JVM in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, jar, jvm, ssl-certificate

I have java sping-boot application running on EC2 instance in AWS, I want to add .crt certificate to the JVM keystore and I have no idea how to do it, if anyone can help or suggest a guide to do it, that will be much appreciated.

Thank you